# Django Rest Framework bulk updates inserting instead of updating

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to build out a bulk update view for a specific model using Django Rest Framework. In the short term, it only needs to update one field (toggling an invite from submitted=False to submitted=True), but I'd like it to be able to provide more functionality in the future. Whenever I test the view, however, a new object is being created instead of the current one being modified.

I feel like this must be a simple mistake on my part, but I can't figure out what's going on. The serializer object appears to be ignoring the value for "id" passed in through JSON, which may be contributing to the issue. Current code is:

```
class InviteBulkUpdateView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        order = self.kwargs['order']
        invite = get_objects_for_user(self.request.user, 'sourcing.view_invite')
        return invite.filter(order=order)

    serializer_class = InviteInputSerializer

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.DATA
        serializer = InviteInputSerializer(data=data, many=True)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class InviteInputSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Invite
        fields = ('id', 'order', 'team', 'submitted')
```

Can anybody shed some light onto what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not passing object instances to your serializer. (Thus it will create new instances rather than update.) See the [docs on dealing with multiple objects in serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects) where you'll see your QuerySet passed in.

Answer (score 11):

Just in case somebody is looking for a library to handle this, I wrote a [Django-REST-Framework-bulk](https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk) which allows to do that in a couple of lines (the example only does bulk update but the library also allows bulk create and delete):

```
from rest_framework_bulk import ListCreateBulkUpdateAPIView

class FooView(ListCreateBulkUpdateAPIView):
    model = FooModel
```

Comment: Django-REST-Framework-bulk appears to no longer be maintained.

Answer (score -1):

Django has update method to handle that. You may want to read full info from [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once).

Here is a sample code where you can use to update given field for multiple records:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException

class Room_Update_ViewSet(APIView):
    def put(self, request,*args, **kwargs):
        hotel_id = self.kwargs.get('hotel_id')
        room_ids = self.request.query_params.get('room_ids')
        room_ids = list(map(int, room_ids.split(',')))
        try:
            Room.objects.filter(hotel_id=hotel_id,id__in=room_ids).update(booked_status=False)
            instances = Room.objects.filter(hotel_id=hotel_id,id__in=room_ids)
            serializer = RoomSerializer(instance=instances, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error udating rooms-->",e)
            raise APIException
```